Question on relationship between OEIS entries A020498 and A172407
OEIS entry A020498 is defined as "a(n) is the least number > a(n-1) such that a(1) through a(n) do not contain all residues modulo any prime".

OEIS entry A172407 is defined as "Positive numbers n such that n+10 is a prime".

These two OEIS entries cross-reference each other perhaps only because many of the elements of A020498 are also in A172407, but I'm wondering if there's a deeper relationship.

Consider the summatory functions
$$A(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} a(n)\tag{1}$$
and
$$B(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} b(n)\tag{2}$$
where $a(n)$ is the indicator function
$$a(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n\in\text{A020498} \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}$$
and $b(n)$ is the indicator function
$$b(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n\in\text{A172407} \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n+10\in\mathbb{P} \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{4}$$
respectively.

Now consider the formulas
$$A(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} f(n)\, B\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\tag{5}$$
and
$$B(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} g(n)\, A\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\tag{6}$$
where
$$a(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} f(d)\, b\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{7}$$
and
$$b(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} g(d)\, a\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{8}$$

Based on the table at the end of this question, it seems that
$$g(n)=f^{-1}(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 f(1) & n=1 \\
 -f(n) & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{9}$$
where $f^{-1}(n)$ is the Dirichlet inverse of $f(n)$ which is a relationship I haven't previously noticed in other arithmetic functions.


Question (1): Does the relationship between $g(n)$ and $f(n)$ illustrated in formula (9) above imply anything deeper about the relationship between OEIS entries A020498 and A172407 other than many of the elements of A020498 are also in A172407?


Question (2): Are there any more well-known and widely-studied arithmetic functions which exhibit the relationship between $f(n)$ and its Dirichlet inverse $f^{-1}(n)$ illustrated in formula (9) above?


The following table omits values of $n$ for which $f(n)=g(n)=0$.

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & f(n) & g(n) & g(n)=-f(n) \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{False} \\
 61 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 93 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 111 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 127 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 133 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 159 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 171 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 177 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 181 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 183 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 199 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 211 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 219 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 223 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 229 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 243 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 259 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 279 & 2 & -2 & \text{True} \\
 289 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 297 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 301 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 303 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 309 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 313 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 327 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 333 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 351 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 357 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 369 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 379 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 381 & 2 & -2 & \text{True} \\
 391 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 393 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 397 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 399 & -2 & 2 & \text{True} \\
 409 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 427 & 2 & -2 & \text{True} \\
 433 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 447 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 457 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 463 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 471 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 477 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 481 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 507 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 513 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 517 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 531 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 543 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 547 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 549 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 561 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 567 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 573 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 577 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 579 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 589 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 597 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 601 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 603 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 619 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 633 & -2 & 2 & \text{True} \\
 637 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 651 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 657 & 2 & -2 & \text{True} \\
 661 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 663 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 667 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 669 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 687 & 2 & -2 & \text{True} \\
 691 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 699 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 703 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 717 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 727 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 729 & -2 & 2 & \text{True} \\
 751 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 757 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 783 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 787 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 793 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 811 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 817 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 837 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 847 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 853 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 859 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 861 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 867 & -2 & 2 & \text{True} \\
 873 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 883 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 889 & 2 & -2 & \text{True} \\
 891 & 2 & -2 & \text{True} \\
 897 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 903 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 913 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 919 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 927 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 931 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 943 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 957 & -1 & 1 & \text{True} \\
 969 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 981 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 993 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
 997 & 1 & -1 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}$$

Say that two sets $S$, $T$ of $n$ integers each have the same shape if there is some $k$ where $T=\{s+k: s\in S\}$.
An admissible $n$-tuple is a set $S$ of $n$ integers such that there are infinitely many $n$-tuples of the same shape as $S$ which consist of $n$ primes, that is, infinitely many $k$ where $S+k$ consists of $n$ primes.
A020498 is concerned specifically with admissible $n$-tuples $T_n$ where $T_1=\{1\}$ and $T_n$ is the earliest admissible $n$-tuple which contains $T_{n-1}$ as its lowest $n-1$ elements. Now let $l_n$ be the lowest integer in any set $S$ of $n$ primes where $S$ has the same shape as $T_n$.
For low $n$, you don't have to go as far as 11 to find the first all-prime $n$-tuple of the same shape as the first admissible $n$-tuple.
For example, take $n=2$. The first admissible duple is (1, 3), and you don't have to go as far as (11, 13) for an example; there's one at (3, 5), so $l_2=3$.
Now take $n=3$. The first admissible triple of form $(1, 3, a_3)$ with $a_3>3$ is $(1, 3, 7)$. And you don't have to go as far as 11 for an example. 3 won't serve, because 9 isn't prime, but there's one at (5, 7, 11), so $l_3=5$.
$l_n\geqslant l_{n-1}$; if $l_n<l_{n-1}$ then there'd be an all-prime $n-1$-tuple of the same shape as $T_{n-1}$, but starting at $l_n$. But $l_{n-1}$ is defined as being the lowest such. So $l_n\geqslant l_{n-1}$.
As we have seen, as $n$ increases, sometimes $l_n>l_{n-1}$. What you've observed is that $l_n=11$ for several $n$. But eventually, adding the next prime to $T_{n-1}$ fails to make a valid $T_n$ because it will cover the last remaining residue modulo 11. This happens at $n=16$: $\{11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67\}$ is 15 primes and has the same shape as $T_{15}$. The next prime is 71. But $T_{15}\cup\{71\}$ covers all 11 residues modulo 11, so we must search elsewhere for $T_{16}$.
